# Public WLAN: Accessing .NET 8 WebAPI Results in Error

Tags: vue.js, axios, asp.net-core-webapi, wifi, asp.net-core-8

I have a Vue.JS (Quasar) web application frontend with an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API backend, hosted on Microsoft IIS windows server. The server runs in my private home, IP is bind to a domain and firewall ports are opened (HTTPS:443/WebAPI:8000). I use https encryption with a certificate.

The web application works well if using mobile phone in my wifi, works well if using mobile data connection. But on *some* public wifi and *some* private wifi, it does not work.

The web page is visible then, but the web api requests fail.

Error (I use Axios):

> Network error - method: GET, Url: "https://YYY:8000/api/XXX"

Does anybody know where the problem is? Is it possible that the port is blocked? Which port to use then?

Comment: Hi @user2353870, Check the logs on both the frontend and backend for more detailed error messages. This can help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: The IIS logs say that the browser requested the page source (which makes sense, the page is displayed), but it does not show any connections to the web api. So it seems that the access to the web page (443) works, access to web api (8000) doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Public Wifi spots are very common to block ports, not only common ports (1433, etc) but many utilize a only allow 80/443 or similar process.

You could look at more logging, but I'd guess a firewall block and you will not see anything incoming on your local server.

You may see similar in corporate environments with more restrictive networks.

Comment: This is also what I suspect. But how do other web pages like google work then? Let they run both the api and the page run on port 443?